# Is there any way to get back the conversation between bot and user on webchat (directline) in nodejs bot framework V4

Tags: node.js, bots, botframework, direct-line-botframework

there is a [way](https://github.com/EricDahlvang/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/eric/node_conversationHistory/samples/javascript_nodejs/22.conversation-history) to do so but the class used here to store the conversations had been deprecated and the flow of defining and writing code is also old style so if there is any new sample for the same then please update.

I have tried the sample with old versions of classes, the sample works fine but I need to use latest class to store the conversation.

```js
let transcriptStore = new AzureBlobTranscriptStore({
  storageAccountOrConnectionString: blobStorageConfig.connectionString,
  containerName: blobStorageConfig.container,
});

var transcriptMiddleware = new TranscriptLoggerMiddleware(transcriptStore);
adapter.use(transcriptMiddleware);
```

This ***AzureBlobTranscriptStore*** has been deprecated. I'm using ***BlobsTranscriptStore*** instead of this. But I'm not able to fetch transcripts from container. I think one of the reason of not getting transcripts is because when I looked in blobStorage container ***AzureBlobTranscriptStore*** class is storing data in specific *channelId* folder but ***BlobsTranscriptStore*** class is storing the data directly in a hierarchy.

This below method is used to get all the transcripts from container. And in new Class this method is also same with the same arguments, but still not able to fetch all the transcripts.

```js
var pagedTranscript =
            await this.transcriptStore.getTranscriptActivities(
              turnContext.activity.channelId,
              turnContext.activity.conversation.id,
              continuationToken
            );
```

So Please let me know if there any possible solution to this problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.